# Will deprecated Google Sign-In scopes stop working?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-openid, google-profiles-api

Looks like Google has deprecated the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile  
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

When will they completely stop working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. They will not stop working.

> We are deprecating the following userinfo endpoints and scopes as of September 1, 2014 — *we will maintain them and keep them available for backward compatibility*
>
> - Deprecating the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` scope in favor of the equivalent `profile` scope or the broader `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope.
> - Deprecating the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scope in favor of the equivalent `email` scope.

[Migrating to Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#changes)

However it is recommended that you don't continue to use deprecated features so you should simply update your scopes to be `profile` and `email`.

Comment: This is correct. The `profile` and `email` scopes are 100% equivalent to the longer userinfo versions, so you can simply replace usage of the old ones with the new shorter ones (and continue to use the old ones for a while). This change was made to align better with the OpenID Connect standard.